# How to access style files in texlive-publishers from Kile

Tags: texlive, kile, publishing

I installed `texlive-publishers` for Ubuntu 11.10 but I don't know where all the class files got installed.

They look to be installed under `/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex`.

So with my rudimentary knowledge of linux I added `/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex` to my path in my `.bashrc` file.

I am assuming that Kile should be able to access stuff from this folder if I include a `\documentclass[...]` in my file.

I just want confirmation that what I did was correct because off late I've been messing up with my linux files and folders quite bad!

Comment: If you installed the package with Synaptic (or equivalent) you shouldn't need anything particular. Adding to the PATH variable serves no purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to run (in shell) the executable `texhash` or `mktexlsr` to make things working. These programs handle LaTeX's file lookup. You should not need any PATH then.

Comment: By 'rudimentary knowledge', I suspect he used APT (or some frontend) to install the bundle, which means `texhash` or `mktexlsr` should be unnecessary.

Comment: Should be, but I suppose that when he asks, he has a problem, and so far `mktexlsr` has solved all my problems with LaTeX searching files that were somewhere in its tree.

Comment: @tohecz `texhash` and `mktexlsr` give me the following messages: `écrivez> texhash
texhash: /usr/local/share/texmf: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: /var/lib/texmf: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: /var/lib/texmf: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: /var/lib/texmf: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: Done.`

Comment: @DNA you should run it as root, try `sudo texhash` or `su <ENTER><type your password> texhash` (or the same with the 2nd executable)

Comment: @tohecz I just did that and my terminal said the following: `texhash: Updating /usr/local/share/texmf/ls-R... 
` I am guessing thats a good thing...