# LaTeX cannot find my personal packages

Tags: packages, mac, mactex, texmf

I'm venturing into writing my own packages, but LaTeX is not finding them.

I working on a iMac OS X, but I don't want to use `TEXMFHOME=~/Library/texmf`.  I would like to put my packages in a different directory: for the sake of this post let's call it `~/private/texmf`.

My `TEXINPUTS` is set as `TEXINPUTS=.:~/private/texmf//:` and works perfectly well for standard `.tex` files.  But when I place a new `.sty` file in these directories, LaTeX complains that they can't be found.

I've tried numerous things.  The two most notable are:

1. Setting `TEXMFHOME=~/private/texmf:~Library/texmf`
2. Setting `TEXMFHOME=~/private/texmf`

Both times, I've entered `~/private/texmf` and run `sudo texhash` to update everything (I've never had to do this before).  I've moved to the directory in which my packages are located `~/private/texmf/tex/latex/packages/` and called `texhash` again.  All to no avail.

I've search the web and this site for clues about what to do:

1. [Change TEXMFHOME per-user](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66614/22413)
2. [Where do I place my own .sty files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/22413)
3. [How to access style files in texlive-publishers from Kile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42313/22413)

   What's mentioned above is what seemed to be suggested at various different sites.  Nothing's working.

Help.

Comment: Have you run `texhash` to update your TDS?

Comment: What is my TDS?

Comment: Sorry, try `mktexlsr`; I'm not sure `texhash` is still supported/active. TDS refers to your TeX Directory Structure.

Comment: Now things are working.  Not sure why.

Comment: Did you run `mktexlsr` or `texhash`?

Comment: I did both.  Most recently `mktexlsr`.

Comment: `mktexlsr` (perhaps formerly known as `texhash`, not sure), is a procedure that updates a reference list to your TDS. This reference list is searched when looking for packages that are not located in the root folder where your source document resides.

Comment: One advantage (which should also be true on OSX, I suppose) of using the standard location for `TEXMFHOME` is that you don't need to use `mktexlsr` when you add a new file.  I'm kind of surprised, in fact, that there isn't a way to make your new location automatically searched just as `~/texmf` (or, I think, `~/Library/texmf`) is.

Comment: Another idea: symlink your directory.  I think you can use this command on OSX: `ln -st ~/texmf/tex/latex/ ~/private/texmf`.  (Note: I assume these are personal latex files.)

Comment: @jon: Isn't TEXMFHOME, as opposed to TEXMFLOCAL and TEXMFDIST, usually configured to not use a ls-R database anyway? I seem to recall this used to be the case in TeXLive.

Comment: I keep all the packages that I write in a separate directory and then add symbolic links to them in my `~/Library/texmf`

Comment: @AlanMunn isn't that quite annoying as you will need to create a new symlink for every file that you add, rather than adding your own directory once?

Comment: @Tom I guess it's a matter of taste. I like my local `texmf` directory to accurately reflect what's in it, and so separate links to each package directory (not each file) is more transparent than a single link to the other directory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The location of the "private tree" is normally, with MacTeX,

```
~/Library/texmf
```

to which the (pseudo)variable `TEXMFHOME` points:

```
> kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFHOME
/Users/<user>/Library/texmf
```

(I only masked my real user name on this machine). If you try

```
> less $(kpsewhich texmf.cnf)
```

you'll get on your screen something like

```
% (Public domain.)
% This texmf.cnf file should contain only your personal changes from the
% original texmf.cnf (for example, as chosen in the installer).
%
% That is, if you need to make changes to texmf.cnf, put your custom
% settings in this file, which is .../texlive/YYYY/texmf.cnf, rather than
% the distributed file (which is .../texlive/YYYY/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf).
% And include *only* your changed values, not a copy of the whole thing!
%
TEXMFHOME = ~/Library/texmf
TEXMFVAR = ~/Library/texlive/2013/texmf-var
TEXMFCONFIG = ~/Library/texlive/2013/texmf-config
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf.cnf (END)
```

The last line doesn't belong to the file, it just shows its location. This file is the top level `texmf.cnf` so the first to be read in when a TeX program is launched; the system is set up so that no variable is clobbered when other `texmf.cnf` files are input.

Thus what you have to do is simply editing that file

```
sudo nano $(kpsewhich texmf.cnf)
```

(use whatever editor you prefer instead of `nano`); for instance, you might want to set

```
TEXMFHOME=~/private/texmf:~Library/texmf
```

I tested it and files are found in both locations (precedence to `~/private/texmf`). You *don't* need to run `texhash` or `mktexlsr` after adding files to the private tree or trees. However, you have to properly create a structure in the tree; a file such as `wonderfulpackage.sty` can be found by LaTeX only if it's stored as

```
~/private/texmf/tex/latex/wonderfulpackage/wonderfulpackage.sty
```

(the last subdivision, that is, the directory `wonderfulpackage`) is optional, but its usage is recommended for later maintenance. If you put the file just at `~/private/texmf` it *will not* be found by LaTeX.

Comment: This *could* be problematic. http://www.tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2012-July/032005.html and the rest of the documentation in this thread.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I read it, but I don't see how this might cause problems. In my test, files are found both in `~/private/texmf` and `~/Library/texmf` trees.

Comment: Finding files is not the problem. The question is if some scripts expect texmfhome to expand to a single directory (like the problem starting the thread where updmap expected texmflocal to contain only one directory). It is quite possible that it works without problems (as there has been a bit pressure due to some discussions about "how to add more trees like in miktex).