# TeX can't find .sty file

Tags: packages, mac

I'm trying to add a commutative diagrams .sty, called diagrams.sty, and TeX is not able to locate it. I placed it in /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex, where I see lots of other packages stored. Am I placing it in the wrong directory? I'm on a Mac and am compiling with pdflatex via terminal.

Other questions similar to this haven't resolved my problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: According to [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1167/51022), your own packages should be placed under your home folder. If you are trying to install extra packages, use *TeX Live Utility*. In the latter case, you can also try `tikz-cd` instead.

Comment: Try putting `diagrams.sty` in a folder `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/diagrams/` and then give `mktexlsr` from terminal as root.

Comment: Or put it in your home TEXMF directory which may be `/Users/username/texmf/'. Then you'd make a directory `/Users/username/texmf/tex/latex/diagrams/' and put the file there. No need to run any additional commands or use root in that case.

Comment: @Symbol1 You can't use TLU to install a package which is not part of TeX Live, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Your home TEXMF directory is revealed by the command `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFHOME`. Whatever it reveals, add the subdirectories `tex/latex/diagrams` as cfr said and put the file in there.

Comment: See for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119898/latex-cannot-find-my-personal-packages

Comment: @cfr istr explaining, to the author, this difficulty of making the package non-free.  non-free implies not in tex live, and (mostly) no miktex (i've observed cases where miktex has taken something i would label non-free, but this may be long enough ago that it was before some rule change.

Comment: @wasteofspace Not sure what you're referring to? Is `diagrams.sty` even on CTAN? In general, MiKTeX is more permissive in terms of licensing restrictions than TeX Live i.e. TL will exclude packages for licensing reasons which MiKTeX will include.